# System of polynomials with no solution over $\mathbb{C}$ and equations modulo primes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Assume that I have a system of polynomials in $f_1,\ldots,f_k\in \mathbb{Z}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ that generate the unit ideal in $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$. Can I deduce something about $V(f_1,\ldots,f_k)\subset \mathbb{F}_p^n$. In particular, is the variety empty for large enough $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can conclude that.  This is a special case of what is sometimes called Robinson's principle, which is a direct application of the compactness theorem in first order logic. More explicitly here is how the argument goes:

Consider the following system of axioms (all of which are in the language of first order logic):

A) The field axioms (of which there are finitely many)

B) The existence of elements $a_1,...,a_n$ satisfying $f_i(a_1,...,a_n)=0$ for each (finitely many) $i$

C) The equations: $1+1 \ne0$, $1+1+1 \ne0$ , $1+1+1+1 \ne0$, ... (infinitely many such axioms)

Now if you had solutions to your system of equations for arbitrarily large characteristic, this would imply the existence of a model satisfying any finite subset of these axioms.  The compactness theorem tells us that a set of first order statements has a model iff any finite subset of it has a model.  Therefore a we must have a model satisfying all of these axioms, which is just a solution to the system of equations over a field of characteristic 0, which we assumed did not exist.

Comment: Thanks! I assume that since this relies on the axiom of choice that there is no way to put a bound on the size of $p$ required through this approach?

Comment: You are correct, this method does not give effective bounds. There is more I can say however. The true condition for which characteristics a given system of polynomials will have a solution is whenever the characteristic divides what is known as the resultant of the polynomials.  This can in principle be expressed in terms of the coefficients of the given polynomials, however the expression is quite complicated and I don't think it gives very useful bounds.

Answer (score 1):

The naïve conjecture that  $V(f_1,\ldots,f_k)\subset \mathbb{F}_p^n$ must be empty is false.
A counterexample already in the case $n=1$ is given by $f_1=p\in \mathbb C[X]$, since  $\langle p\rangle =\langle \frac 1 p \cdot p\rangle =\langle  1\rangle\subset  \mathbb C[X]$ but nevertheless $V(p)=V(0)=\mathbb{F}_p\subset \mathbb{F}_p$ is non-empty.
Logical considerations however permit to conclude that for $p$ large enough we  have  $V(f_1,\ldots,f_k)=\emptyset \subset \mathbb{F}_p^n$: see Nate's answer.